# What are the differences between struct_time and datetime?

Tags: python, date-format

Is one preferred over the other? If so, in all cases or just a few?

I am intending to use some form of date class for keeping long lists of date and time data, e.g. `'2009-01-01 10:12:00'`.

Comment: If you run "import datetime;datetime.datetime.today();datetime.datetime.today().timetuple();" - the former is a datetime, the latter is a struct_time. A dir() around the value will expose the API differences - although this does not answer your question.

Comment: `datetime`s are easier to change than an `struct_time`s which are an immutable datatype like a `tuple` (because that's what it is effectively).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

struct_time is the old way of representing times, modeled after the C standard library.  datetime came later, is more pythonic, is more featureful, and has more predictable behavior in edge cases than the struct_time functions.  I would use datetime except in the rare cases where a measured performance difference is significant enough to matter, or where it makes the code significantly less readable.

Answer (score 2):

[`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) is more object oriented and offers many convenient features, e.g. arithmetic with [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)-objects.